# Img tag creating centered content spacing issues?

Tags: html, css, image, github-pages

I've created a static portfolio site for myself in GitHub Pages that is incredibly simple to keep maintenance easy. I have a 3-line title at the top of every page that acts as a navigation. However, I've somehow created a small (10 or so px) shift between the home page and all of the interior pages.

When I inspect the code in DevTools, I can see that the content for both pages is 600px wide with a 25px padding on either side of the content. The horizontal content margins are set to auto to center the main content block on each page, but on the interior pages, the margins are slightly different than the home page.

The home page - https://www.parkermyers.com

An interior page with a single img - https://www.parkermyers.com/about.html

An interior page with multiple img tags - https://parkermyers.com/nighttrain.html

Hopefully you can see that there is a shift in the margins when navigating from the home page to either of the two provided interior pages.

The furthest I've gotten in troubleshooting is that it's probably related to the img tag that is present on all interior pages but not the home page (could possibly be the surrounding figure tags as well). For example, on the /about page of the site, when I delete the lone img, the content margins shift a bit and realign with the home page.

So my best guess is that there's something to do with the width or size of the image that makes the content slightly larger and thus affects the margins, but I've messed around with the width to no success.

Comment: Due to the scroll bar?

Comment: @j08691 I don't see a scroll bar present with any of the images!


Edit: Wait on the page in general? You're correct in that the home page doesn't have enough content to scroll and the other pages do.

Answer (score 0):

The comment that mentioned the scroll bar helped me troubleshoot more efficiently to find a solution for my problem! The issue was not directly the img tag, but the vertical space that the images took up meant that there was a scroll bar on the interior pages and not the home page.

After using that knowledge to dig further, I found that

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

created a permanent space for the scrollbar whether it was being used or not. This solved my alignment issue! A small side effect is that the space for the scroll bar is not invisible when not being used, but it's a small price to pay for consistent alignment.

Comment: Glad that I could point you in the right direction